Grease Pencil "Rim Effect" acting weird with Camera Animation
So, I am working on a short test animation with Grease Pencil. For this, my intention is to have a rough unfinished esthetic to the overall visual language. After arriving at a desirable point, I noticed that the "Rim Effect" I added to my Grease Pencil object is acting weird in relation to the camera dolly out animation. There's this squared off section that reveals the rim Light effect at the right corner of the viewport. It behaves as if the camera dolly out is revealing the rim light effect
See pic below:
Now I thought this was just some viewport camera glitch and that it won't appear in my final render but low and behold, It did. :D
See pic of render stills below below:



This "Mask" seems to be over the rim light effect alone. Once it's turned off every other thing works fine. And regarding mask, no I didn't use masking here.
I would really appreciate any help/advice. So far, I like where I am going with this look. And fixing this issue would mean that I can stick with it. Thank you
